# How to know which version of C language I am using?

Tags: c, linux, version, programming-languages

I write `c` code and run it with `gcc`. Well everything works. But I don't know which version I am using. Today in Wikipedia [C (programming language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) I saw that the latest stable release of this language is `C17 / June 2018; 3 years ago`. So, I am curious to know my version. Is there any way to know this? I am using Ubuntu Linux.

**EDIT:** I want to know the `c` version which used by the `gcc` when i just use `gcc programm.c` or `gcc -o programm.out programm.c`. Actually which `c` version is used by `gcc` by default.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? Use that to check the GCC manual page which C standard version it defaults to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `gcc -v` results `gcc version 9.3.0`

Comment: A single C compiler might implement parts or all of a given C standard and some (gcc among them) can even switch between which version they use. So knowing the specific version of your compiler doesn't necessarily tell you what language version you compile with, you'll have to look at your build files (or more specifically: your compiler command line switches) as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Do you want to say by using `gcc programm.c` I can't know the c language version wich is used for compilation?

Comment: @alhelal: if you don't specify it explicitly, you'll have to check the manual for your version of gcc to see what it uses by default. Usually that is the latest fully implemented C version with GNU extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a predefined macro `__STDC_VERSION__` [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace) in your code. It expands to an `long` integer in `yyyymmL` format (i.e. `199901L` signifies C99).
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc` 9.3 with no flags print:

```
201710
```

While compiled with `-std=c2x` option produces:

```
202000
```

Using a macro will let you handle different versions of C language directly in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant "what version of the C language", then yes of course, you use the `-std` command line option to specify.

[The manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) has a lot to say, it begins:

> -std=
>
> Determine the l standard.   This option is currently only supported when compiling C or C++.

The default, as mentioned by the man page, is `gnu89`, so it's a good idea to change it, to compile C17 code you would do:

```
$ gcc -std=c17 -o my-new-program my-new-program.c
```

The default can change with a new release of GCC, which is another good reason to specify it yourself on the command line if you want to be sure.

If you just meant which compiler release you're using, then that's printed by the `--version` option:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Fresh.

Comment: Is `gnu89` developed by GNU?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) C17 and C11 are effectively the same in GCC (as C17 only contains corrections that are also applied in C11), the only difference being the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`.

Comment: @alhelal: `gnu89` is `c89` with [GNU extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions). It's not technically a "standard", just what gcc calls its own changes/additions to the language.

Comment: @alhelal Yes, GNU have their own dialect of C with some GNU-specific stuff in it. I consuider that sub-optimal for a C ompiler to default to, so that's why I recommend always changing it so you don't risk introducing GNU code (i.e. non-standard code) by mistake which would make switching compilers hard.

Comment: Minor note: the standard value changes with new versions of `gcc`. On my local `gcc 9.3.0` for example the man pages states that `gnu17` is the default for C code.

Comment: ·@JoachimSauer Good point, I edited that in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gcc you can use the following commands to know the compiler version.

```
gcc --version

gcc -v
```

And then you can set `std` to compile a particular version of C in your case c17.

```
gcc -std=c17 sample.c -o sample
```